# Wordpress member acces to custom page/template

Tags: php, wordpress

I have made some custom templates in my wordpress and used it to build 2 pages with. Then I have tried the Members plugin for access control. It work on the pages, but it still shows my custom PHP code on that page. It there a better plugin for this or should my custom php include som standard code from wordpress to be included in the access control?

```
<?php /* Template Name: Storfanger_indberet */ ?>
<?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;

get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary" <?php generate_content_class();?>>
    <main id="main" <?php generate_main_class(); ?>>
        <?php do_action('generate_before_main_content'); ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>

            <!--My code begin -->

            <?php
If($_POST['Submit'])
{
    // run validation if you're not doing it in js
    global $wpdb;

    $medlemsnr=$_POST['medlemsnr'];
    $navn=$_POST['navn'];
    $baadnavn=$_POST['baadnavn'];
    $art=$_POST['art'];
    $vaegt=$_POST['vaegt'];
    $billede=$_POST['billede'];

    if($wpdb->insert(
                        'ct_storfanger_indberetninger',
                        array(
                        'Medlemsnr' => $medlemsnr,
                        'navn' => $navn,
                        'bådnavn' =>$baadnavn,
                        'art' =>$art,
                        'vægt' =>$vaegt,
                        'billede' =>$billede
                        )
                    ) == false) wp_die('Der var en fejl i indsendelsen. Kontakt venligst webmaster'); else echo 'Tak for din indsendelse. Den vil fremgå af listen så snart den er godkendt af juryen!<p />';
?>
<?php
}
else // else we didn't submit the form, so display the form
{
?>

<form action="" method="post" id="form">
<table style="border:none;">
                <tr>
                <td style="border:none;width:25%">Medlemsnr</td>
                <td style="border:none;"><input name="medlemsnr"     type="text" value="" /></td>
                </tr>
            <tr>
            <td style="border:none;">Navn</td>
            <td style="border:none;"><input name="navn" type="text" value="" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td style="border:none;">Bådnavn</td>
            <td style="border:none;"><input name="baadnavn" type="text" value="" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td style="border:none;">Art</td>
            <td style="border:none;">
                <?php 
                global $wpdb;
                $retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT Art FROM ct_storfanger_arter");
            ?>
            <SELECT NAME="art"><option value=""></option>
            <?php
                foreach ($retrieve_data as $retrieved_data){ 
                    echo "<option value='" . $retrieved_data->Art . "'>" . $retrieved_data->Art . "</option>";
                }
            ?>
            </SELECT></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td style="border:none;">Vægt i gram</td>
            <td style="border:none;"><input name="vaegt" type="text" value="" /> gram</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td style="border:none;">Billede</td>
            <td style="border:none;"><input name="billede" type="file" value="" /></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <table style="border:none;">
            <tr>
            <td style="border:none;"><input type="submit" name="Submit" id="formsubmit" value="Indsend" /></form></td>
            </tr>
            </table>

            </form>
<?php
    } // end else no post['submit']
?>              

            <!--My code ends -->

            <?php
            // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template
            if ( comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number() ) : ?>
                <div class="comments-area">
                    <?php comments_template(); ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>

        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
        <?php do_action('generate_after_main_content'); ?>
    </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
<?php 
do_action('generate_sidebars');
get_footer();
?>
```

Comment: Most of the membership plugins for WordPress will hide content which is coming from WP standard loop etc. The custom php code you have there, might need to be wrapped inside Member Plugin's custom php function to manage its access/visibility control?

Comment: I hear you, but don't quite understand :)
Where do I need to do something?

Comment: Can you share the page, if i understand correctly you are outputing something via custom php which is being shown even when you have made the page private via Members plugin, is that the case?

Comment: yes that is exactly the case. Thats my custom template page. When i'm not logged in and go to this page, its says thats it forbidden and I have to log in, but still shown my PHP code and the html form

Comment: Well after checking if the user is not logged in and echoing the warning can't you just exit() the php process and end the page rendering? (in case the check is done before page render, otherwise the check itself is useless) -i'd spit out alert warning and after clicking "OK" it would redirect the visitor back to homepage.

Comment: Well my problem is that i'm not doing the check of the user. That's the plugin that does that. So what you suggest is it's own user logged in check, right?

Comment: @KristianC i mean.. Wordpress is good reliable system... What makes it vulnerable and slow are bad admins and bad plugins... I try to keep my WP installation slim with minimum plugins, with correct webserver restrictions (IP, posts, gets, paths, CDN etc) and do a lot of stuff proprietary... A lot o community plugins are security terror.

I mean take a look at it - the code just for check user role is really short and easy to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

You can put this code at the start of your custom theme template to restrict access.

```
<?php /* Template Name: Admin/Editor access */

      if(!is_user_logged_in())$getOut=true;//Check if visitor is even logged in
      elseif(current_user_can('editor') || current_user_can('administrator')){//Is user administrator or editor?
         $getOut=false;//User can stay and view the content (even process scripts)
      }
      if($getOut){//Should the user be kicked out?
      echo"<html><body>";
         echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('You don\'t have permission to do that');"
              ."window.location.href = '/';</script></body></html>";//Throw out warning
         exit();//Anything below won't be processed
      }
   get_header(); ?>
```

### Show warning instead of content on regular page

```
<?php /* Template Name: Storfanger_indberet */ ?>
<?php
if (!defined('ABSPATH')) exit;

get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" <?php generate_content_class(); ?>>
        <main id="main" <?php generate_main_class(); ?>>
            <?php do_action('generate_before_main_content'); ?>

            if(!is_user_logged_in())//Check if visitor is even logged in
                $getOut=true;
            elseif(current_user_can('editor') || current_user_can('administrator')){//Is user administrator or editor?
                $getOut=false;//User can stay and view the content (even process scripts)
            }
            if($getOut){//Should the user be kicked out?
                echo"Access denied";
            }else while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php get_template_part('content', 'page'); ?>

            <!--My code begin -->

            <?php
            If ($_POST['Submit']) {
                // run validation if you're not doing it in js
                global $wpdb;

                $medlemsnr = $_POST['medlemsnr'];
                $navn = $_POST['navn'];
                $baadnavn = $_POST['baadnavn'];
                $art = $_POST['art'];
                $vaegt = $_POST['vaegt'];
                $billede = $_POST['billede'];

                if ($wpdb->insert(
                        'ct_storfanger_indberetninger',
                        array(
                            'Medlemsnr' => $medlemsnr,
                            'navn' => $navn,
                            'bådnavn' => $baadnavn,
                            'art' => $art,
                            'vægt' => $vaegt,
                            'billede' => $billede
                        )
                    ) == false
                ) wp_die('Der var en fejl i indsendelsen. Kontakt venligst webmaster'); else echo 'Tak for din indsendelse. Den vil fremgå af listen så snart den er godkendt af juryen!<p />';
                ?>
                <?php
            } else // else we didn't submit the form, so display the form
            {
                ?>

                <form action="" method="post" id="form">
                    <table style="border:none;">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="border:none;width:25%">Medlemsnr</td>
                            <td style="border:none;"><input name="medlemsnr" type="text" value=""/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="border:none;">Navn</td>
                            <td style="border:none;"><input name="navn" type="text" value=""/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="border:none;">Bådnavn</td>
                            <td style="border:none;"><input name="baadnavn" type="text" value=""/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="border:none;">Art</td>
                            <td style="border:none;">
                                <?php
                                global $wpdb;
                                $retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT Art FROM ct_storfanger_arter");
                                ?>
                                <SELECT NAME="art">
                                    <option value=""></option>
                                    <?php
                                    foreach ($retrieve_data as $retrieved_data) {
                                        echo "<option value='" . $retrieved_data->Art . "'>" . $retrieved_data->Art . "</option>";
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                </SELECT></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="border:none;">Vægt i gram</td>
                            <td style="border:none;"><input name="vaegt" type="text" value=""/> gram</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="border:none;">Billede</td>
                            <td style="border:none;"><input name="billede" type="file" value=""/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table style="border:none;">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="border:none;"><input type="submit" name="Submit" id="formsubmit"
                                                            value="Indsend"/>
                </form></td>
                </tr>
                </table>

                </form>
                <?php
            } // end else no post['submit']
            ?>

            <!--My code ends -->

            <?php
            // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template
            if (comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number()) : ?>
                <div class="comments-area">
                    <?php comments_template(); ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
            <?php do_action('generate_after_main_content'); ?>
        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
<?php
do_action('generate_sidebars');
get_footer();
?>
```

[image: Working demontration]

Comment: I haven't tried this, but this shouldn't render anything else than warning and redirect in case user is not logged in and when is logged in, he has to be role editor or admin

Comment: You could simply make this into a function and put it then anywhere in the wp theme again.

Comment: Well... the code does not work as is. I just get a blank page. But I'm using the plugin to control my access. This code is "its own" access control as I understand it, right? Is it not possible to get the/some plugin to control access on custom pages ?

Comment: @KristianC Correct, this shouldn't require any plugins. There most likely are, but i just don't advise using them.. I will try the code on my own website to see if it's working.

Comment: @KristianC my bad 'You don\'t have permission to do that' - there was a javascript syntax error

Comment: Thanks. But why would you not use the plugins to control access?

Comment: @KristianC becase any additional plugin you put in your WP installation makes it slower and possible security hole. If i can do a "mundane" code on my own, i preffer to do it... Years ago when i couldn't code any serversided code, I did use tens of plugins per WP installation - eventually some websites got hacked because of security holes in plugins.

Comment: @KristianC I mean definitely you can use a plugin solution, but then i wouldn't choose a solution, that would require a php code combination. Either one or another. Ideally try to use as least plugins as possible and try to keep everything up to date.

Comment: Okay that makes sence. I am new to PHP and even though I have written a lot of classic ASP many years ago, this is very hard for me :)
Is there any way to show the message on the page instead of a popup? Then I think it would be perfect

Comment: @KristianC that probably won't be hard, I'll update my post

Comment: @KristianC try updated answer... It should show page content "Access denied" instead of post - So it will either echo warning or do the  `}else while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>` **Up to** `<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>`

Comment: K Thank you. That'll do the job. Thank you very much. I'm so pleased with that. Thanks a lot.